# How do you initialize a Lazily loaded collection in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm fairly confused as to how to structure my code when Hibernate is Lazy loading everything.

As I have it now, I get the `Could not initialize proxy - no session` exception when I try to load some data into my object.

The current code looks like this:

**Schedule Class**

```
public class MyScheduler {
  private static ItemRepo repo;
  private static List<Item> myItems;

  public MyScheduler() {
    if (myItems == null) {
      repo = new MyItemHibernateRepository();
      myItems = repo.findAll();
    }
  }
  // ... rest of code
```

**Find All Method v.1**

```
  @Override
  public List<Item> findAll() {
    Session session = openSession();
    List<Item> transfers = 
        (List<Item>) session.createQuery("from Items").list();
    session.close();  
    return transfers;
  }
```

Here, as you can see, I try to load everything from the DB, pack them into a list, and then return them to the caller. However, when I test this, the problem is that they don't actually "load." I try to use them later in the program and I get one of the `No Session` errors.

After reading around a bit, it seems they need to be initialized before the `session` is closed, so, before I close the session, I added a call to `Hibernate.initialize`

**Find All Method v.2**

```
  @Override
  public List<Transfer> findAll() {
    Session session = openSession();
    List<Item> transfers = 
        (List<Item>) session.createQuery("from Items").list();

    transfers.forEach(t -> Hibernate.initialize(t));

    session.close();  
    return transfers;
  }
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
public class HibernateRepository {

  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  static {
    try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
      // config file.
      sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().bunchofclasses.configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      // Log the exception. 
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  public static Session openSession() {
    return getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

However, I still get the same `could not initialize proxy - no Session` error. What do I need to do to properly initialize this?

Comment: provide implementation of `openSession` method

Comment: Paste the stack trace of the exception. We don't even know what Hibernate is trying to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get Find All Method v.2 to work, the way it is written will probably give you bad performance since you are falling into the trap of the infamous [Hibernate N+1 Select problem](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/how-identify-and-resilve-n1).

What you should do is alter your query to fetch the collections you need to have when the session is closed.

For example, let's say Item has a field `Collection<OtherItem> otherItems`. You query would be 
`from Items as i join fetch i.otherItems`.

Note however that the previous query will not return any `Items` that don't have `OtherItems` (use left join fetch if you want to include these as well), and will return multiple identical Items if an `Item` has more than one `OtherItems`.

**UPDATE**

As *JBNizet* correctly pointed out, in order to get past the problem of returning multiple `Items` you would use the following query

`select distinct i from Items as i join fetch i.otherItems` (or you left join fetch to include `Items` whether or not they have `OtherItems`)

Comment: And the correct query should thus be `select distinct i from Items i left join fetch i.otherItems`.

Comment: @JBNizet Absolutely correct! Do you mind if I update my answer with your suggestion?